# What's the value of the segment $MN$ in the figure below?

Tags: plane-geometry

For refrence: In the figure shown:

H ➔ Orthocenter of $\triangle$ ABC; also: BH = 16, AC = 30 and BN = NC

Find: MN

[image]

An important property that can be useful:
$OG = 2BH \therefore BH = 8$
Tracing the circumference circumscribed to the triangle $QBC$
we can get the value of $BC$ and therefore the value of $BN$ and $NC$ and also of $CQ$.

[image]

Comment: How is $M$ defined? The midpoint of the orthocentre and the circumcentre?

Comment: @peterwhy..yes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M$, the midpoint of $OH$, is the centre of the nine-point circle. This circle passes through the midpoints of the sides of the triangle. Therefore, $MN=$ radius of the nine-point circle$=$ $\frac {1}{2}\cdot $ $($ Circumradius of $\triangle ABC$ $)=\boxed {\frac {17}{2}}$ $($Apply Pythagorean Theorem on $\triangle OGC$ $)$.